# nmap output: Variable escape character

Tags: windows, batch-file, nmap

I want to use `nmap` to output an XML file, but it doesn't have a correct path.

This is `1.txt`:

```
192.168.1.0/24
192.168.5.0/24
...
```

This is my code:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (1.txt) do (
  nmap -o -v %%a -oX %%a
)
pause
```

It will show the error

> nmap Failed to open normal output for writing QUITTING

I know it is a path problem, because the output file can't be found (`192.168.1.0/24.xml`)

How to escape the `/` in `192.168.1.0/24` when I output the `%%a` variable? Because I want output file name like `192.168.1.0/24.xml`.

Comment: Remove `@echo off` temporarily to see what `%%a` is expanded to...

Comment: A file name can't contain any of the following characters: `/ \ : * ? " < > |`  Recommend replacing the forward slash with a dash to illustrate the address range.

Comment: I know the file name can't use "/" , but the %%a is load from txt
It's any way to change %%a (192.168.1.0/24) to (192.168.1.0-255)?
If I don't wan't change text file content ??

Comment: Doing interpretation of subnetting in batch is not a trivial thing and not in scope of this question.

Comment: Network ID/mask calculation is fairly simple in PowerShell, though: `([IPAddress] (([IPAddress] "192.168.1.22").Address -band ([IPAddress] "255.255.255.0").Address)).IPAddressToString` outputs `192.168.1.0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The forward slash is a [reserved character](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247.aspx) that can't be used in a filename. [Replace](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490998.aspx) it with something valid (e.g. an underscore). Enable [delayed expansion](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060823-00/?p=29993) to make the replacement work inside the `for` loop.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (1.txt) do (
  set "net=%%a"
  set "filename=!net:/=_!.xml"
  nmap -o -v !net! -oX "!filename!"
)

pause
```

That will give you output filenames like `192.168.1.0_24.xml`. A filename `192.168.1.0/24.xml` simply isn't possible on Windows.